# Event bindings lost after refreshing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, best-in-place

I'm using the rails gem best_in_place and am trying to reload the div it is in upon submit.

```
$('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:success", function(){
    $(.'div').load(location.href+" .div>*","");
});
```

However, the event binding is gone once i refresh the div. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

bind does not work if you recreate the div again. In that case it is better to use 'on' instead of bind which is live.

```
$('.best_in_place').on("ajax:success", function(){
    $(.'div').load(location.href+" .div>*","");
});
```